# Matrices over quaternions make Hopf Algebra or not?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, quaternions, hopf-algebras

I am learning Hopf algebra now a days. I am still confused about it’s axioms. I don’t know how to define antipode structure. What are the basic rules to define it. ? Can any one help me to solve this problem that matrices over quaternions are Hopf algebra or not?your answers will be highly appreciated. Even someone can also provide me the difference in the hopf algebra structure for Matrices over complex field and matrices over quaternions.

Comment: Please someone answer. I’m in great trouble ☹️

Comment: What is the bialgebra structure? Can you provide some context?

Comment: Bialgebra means any vector space over field satisfying algebra and coalgebra axioms. I mean having unit counit multiplication and comultiplication.

Comment: Yes, what is the specific comultiplication you have in mind? Even for matrices over the complex field?

Comment: Counit maps the matrix to kronicker delta.,unit take  quaternion and result into matrix representation of quaternion, comultiplication simply take a matrix in quaternion and split it into tw matrices . Antipode structure doesn’t satisfy if I take antipode to be  adjoint of matrix.. I’m not sure about my thinking and I don’t know exactly how to write them in mathematical notation explicitly.

Comment: No one has replied ☹️

Comment: If you could actually write out your progress so far, in terms of defining both the algebra and coalgebra structure, it could help people answer. I don't know how the space of matrices forms a bialgebra.

Comment: Actually I can’t write here the mathematical notations.

Comment: Also there is not any option for picture upload. Or pdf so that I can upload here

Comment: There is [a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to write mathematical notation on this site.

Comment: May be I can share you by my email. Can you share please?

Comment: you can upload the image somewhere and then link it here. Anyway I'm quite sure you could work out an Hopf Algebra with matrices of quaterions. Check if you just can generalize this one https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0112118.pdf

Comment: Thank you so much I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

Quaternions form an algebra over the reals, so I assume you look for real bialgebra structures. In particular you need a counit that must be an algebra map $M_n(\mathbb H)\to \mathbb R$. If you restrict to real matrices you get an algebra map from matrices to the reals. There are no such, unless n=1. Also, for n=1, there is no algebra map from quaternions to reals. So, there is no bialgebra structures on matrices over the quaternions.

Comment: I would appreciate the explanation of the down vote

Comment: This seems to be the right answer. The kernel of the co-unit must be a two-sided ideal in $M_n(\mathbb{H})$, but the latter is a simple algebra.